# tq_index error, its creating an excel file?

Tags: r, tidyquant

For some reason, I im getting this error when I run:

```
DOW = tq_index("DOW")
```

and the error:

```
Getting holdings for DOW
Error at DOW during download. 
Error: Evaluation error: zip file 'C:\Users\mbhe\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpA59N1Y\file1bf4feb669b.xlsx' cannot be opened.
```

This excel file is different every time, so if I run it again, I will get the same error, but a new excel will be created and reported in the error.

This is the first time my R Studio have done this.
Does any of you guys know how to fix this? When i look around the internet, this error only occurs when you actually try to load a excel file, not when you want to get info from tq_index.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an issue with `tidyquant` package.

You can try `DOW = quantmod::getQuote("^DJI")`

Comment: I want the tickers of the index, so all of the companies in the dow.
Oh ok, as long as its not my fault, so I know it will work again at some point!